# grep from 7 GB text file OR many smaller ones

Tags: bash

I have about two thousand text files in folder.

I want to loop each one and search for specific word in line.

```
for file in "./*.txt";
do
    cat $file | grep "banana"
done
```

I was wondering if join all text files into one file would be faster.

The whole directory has about 7 GB.

Comment: There’s no need to use `cat` there and most likely doesn’t matter if the files are one or many

Comment: And is there some proof?

Comment: Benchmark it if you think it matters. There’s many variables but the time needed for opening a file is minimal compared to reading gigabytes of data

Comment: if your disk system can support multiple reads, consider running parallel `grep` operations against the smaller files

Comment: Why not just `grep "banana" *.txt`, you will save 2000 processes and if the file names are not too long it won't reach the max command line limit

Comment: Try with **GNU Parallel** if you have decent disks `parallel grep "banana" {} ::: *.txt`

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano `*.txt` result in an error depending on the size of the filenames and the operating system limit on the length of a command line.

Comment: @PhillipJacobs I don't think this is a great edit: the tag [tag:terminal] is not related to this, and saying "this takes quite a while" implies something the author didn't say - especially considering that the command they show does *not* loop as they assume.

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually looping, you're calling `cat` just once on the string `./*.txt`, i.e., your script is equivalent to

```
cat ./*.txt | grep 'banana'
```

This is *not* equivalent to

```
grep 'banana' ./*.txt
```

though, as the output for the latter would prefix the filename for each match; you could use

```
grep -h 'banana' ./*.txt
```

to suppress filenames.

The problem you could run into is that `./*.txt` expands to something that is longer than the maximum command line length allowed; to prevent that, you could do something like

```
printf '%s\0' ./*.txt | xargs -0 grep -h 'banana'
```

which is save for both files containing blanks and shell metacharacters *and* calls `grep` as few times as possible<sup>1</sup>.

This can even be parallelized; to run 4 `grep` processes in parallel, each handling 5 files at a time:

```
printf '%s\0' ./*.txt | xargs -0 -L 5 -P 4 grep -h 'banana'
```

---

What I think you intended to run is this:

```sh
for file in ./*.txt; do
    cat "$file" | grep "banana"
done
```

which would call `cat`/`grep` once per file.

---

<sup>1</sup>At first I thought that `printf` would run into trouble with command line length limitations as well, but it seems that as a shell built-in, it's exempt:

```
$ touch '%s\0' {1000000..10000000} > /dev/null
-bash: /usr/bin/touch: Argument list too long
$ printf '%s\0' {1000000..10000000} > /dev/null
$
```

Comment: Depending on the desired output, piping the output of the loop itself to `grep` may be better: `for file in ./*.txt; do cat "$file"; done | grep "banana"`

Comment: `find` has a fail safe for `argmax` see https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/

Comment: @Jetchisel Yes, `find -exec {} +` is a good alternative - the only drawback I know of is that it can't be parallelized.